# Wired internet connection stopped working

Tags: internet

For a few days I haven't been able to connect to internet through a wired connection on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have searched online for different solutions, but none seemed to work. Could someone please help me? Just tell me which files you would like to see in order to detect my problem and I will post them here.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:22:92:ec  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe22:92ec/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8556 (8.5 KB)  TX bytes:58317 (58.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:225543 (225.5 KB)  TX bytes:225543 (225.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:8b:fd:3e:60:5c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:71517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:52476 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:75661556 (75.6 MB)  TX bytes:7703598 (7.7 MB)
```

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. I've done it earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please let's know whether this is a Laptop or PC,  if this is a laptop - then the Network driver might not configured or installed.

We can solve this issue by installing the proper network driver.

For this you need to download the latest drivers from the below URL,

http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/

Once its download, open your terminal window - go to the download location and extract the download file.

```
tar -xvf compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p.tar.bz2
```

just execute the below command one after another,

```
cd compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p

scripts/driver-select alx

make

sudo make install

sudo modprobe alx
```

Now do a restart and check this resolves this issue,

Comment: We are talking about a laptop. Looking through the link you posted, I see that th drivers are related to the wireless. My wi-fi connection works just fine. I have problems with my ethernet connection.

Comment: + It was working perfectly until a few days ago when it suddenly stopped working.